# How to connect socket to the remote device in android using ionic?

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, socket.io

I am developing my ***ionic app using angularjs***. I want to ***find the location of multiple devices & show it in google map.***
   As per my R & D, Without using server we can achieve this using ***socket connection***.

I am new to this socket connection.

Can any one tell me, how to **establish socket connection**?

How to get the **location of other devices** in our app?

Using **socket.io liabrary** we can acheive this for cordova?

***Anyone help will be Appreciated!!!***